# Proving $f(x) = x^2 \sin(1/x)$, $f(0)=0$ is differentiable at $0$, with derivative $f'(0)= 0$ at zero

Tags: derivatives

I need a solution for this question. I've been trying out this question for days and I haven't been able to find out its solution yet. And some explanation would help too.

> Show that the function f defined by:
>   $$f(x):= \begin{cases}
>   x^2\sin(1/x) &:\text{if $x \ne 0$} \\
>   0 &:\text{if $x=0$}
> \end{cases}$$
>   is differentiable at $x=0$, and that $f'(0)=0$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232672/show-that-the-function-gx-x2-sin-frac1x-g0-0-is-everywhere

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**: We have $-x^2 \le f(x) \le x^2$, hence 
$$ -x \le \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x-0} = \frac{f(x)}x \le x $$
for $x \ne 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$\bullet\;\;\text{If $\,f,g\,$ are two functions defined in some punctured neighborhood I$_0$ of $\;x_0\;$ and s.t.:}$$

$$\begin{align*}(1)&\;\;\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=0\\{}\\
(2)&\,\exists\,M\in\Bbb R\;\;s.t.\;\;|g(x)|\le M\;\;\forall\,x\in\text{I}_0\end{align*}$$

$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$then $\;\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)g(x)=0}$

$$\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\bullet\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=\lim_{x\to x_0}\;x\sin\frac1x\;\;\ldots\ldots$$