# Why does the shortcut method for checking differentiability not working here?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I had learnt about the shortcut method of checking differentiability from a certain book few months back.

**I am illustrating the shorcut method I had learnt here using an example:**

> Is $|x-1/9|^3$ differentiable at $x=1/9$
>
> For $x>1/9$ $f(x)=(x-1/9)^3$ Differentiate w.r.t x and put $x=1/9$.Say
>   the value of the derivative is $a$.
>
> For $x<1/9$ $f(x)=-(x-1/9)^3$ Differentiate w.r.t x and put
>   $x=1/9$.Say the value of the derivative is $b$.
>
> If $a=b$ then it is differentiable at $x=1/9$
>
> This method works because $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=1/9$

But recently I came across a function like:

$f(x)= \begin{cases} 
      0 & x= 0 \\
      2x+x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x}) &x \neq0 
 \end{cases}$

Even though $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$ the shortcut method does not seem to work here.

For $x>0$ $f'(x)=2+2x\sin(\frac{1}{x})+x^2\cos(\frac{1}{x})(\frac{-1}{x^2})$.

But here when I put $x=0$, $f'(x)$ becomes undefined.

However using the limit definition of derivative I am getting the value of derivative at $x=0$ as $2$.

Why isn't the shortcut method not valid here ? On the other hand why is the limit definition of derivative valid and working ? Does the derivative of $f(x)$ really exist at $x=0$ ?

Comment: You need that the **limit of $f'$ at $x=0$** exists and $f$ is continuous in $0$. You misunderstood the shortcut.

Comment: Why should the limit of f' exist at x=0 ? Can you point me to any online resource which says so ? Or could you explain the reason behind it ? @user251257

Comment: look in the proof of your shortcut

Comment: @user251257 I don't have the proof of my shortcut. I can't remember where I learnt it from.

Comment: then ask a new question for the proof or use the search function.

Comment: @user251257 Okay. Thanks.

Comment: This is a wiered function .  https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://math.jhu.edu/~spindler/summercalc1hw913solutionsv2.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjf68yF_dnQAhUBLY8KHYSTDW0QFghHMA4&usg=AFQjCNEbDU8f5zodQHy0sMqsFaFwleY79w

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/400081/proving-fx-x2-sin1-x-f0-0-is-differentiable-at-0-with-derivati

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no contradiction:

This is a great example of the derivative *existing* pointwise, although not being *continuous*.

Hence the given function is continuous and differentiable, but **not** *continuously differentiable*.