# Example or disprove for an $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Does there exists an $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ differentiable everywhere with $f'$ discontinuous at some point?

Comment: Cantor-Volterra's functionis an example of differentiable function whose derivative has discontinuity set of positive measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there does exist such a function, for example
$$f(x)=\cases{x^2\sin(1/x)&if $x\ne0$\cr 0&if $x=0$.\cr}$$
By normal differentiation rules we have
$$f'(x)=2x\sin(1/x)-\cos(1/x)$$
if $x\ne0$, and for $x=0$ we use the definition:
$$f'(0)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h-0}=\lim_{h\to0}h\sin(1/h)=0\ .$$
So $f$ is certainly differentiable at $0$, and in fact everywhere else too.  However, if $x\to0$ then $2x\sin(1/x)\to0$ and $\cos(1/x)$ oscillates between $1$ and $-1$, so $f'(x)$ has no limit as $x\to0$, and is therefore not continuous at $x=0$.

Comment: $\lim_{h \to 0} h \sin (1/h)=1$, but your argument works well.

Comment: @David Thank you, I realize that the other function suggested indeed didn't work. Also, there is a post about this particular function. I am posting it for future reference: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232672/show-that-the-function-gx-x2-sin-frac1x-g0-0-is-everywhere

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  Do you know an example of a continuous function that is not differentiable at some point? (Hint:  think of a corner)  If you integrate it....

Comment: OK got it, thank you. I was thinking it from another point of view, didn't try integrating a function.

Comment: The point of the exercise is that each level of differentiability brings something new in information about (restricting) the function.  You can have a function that is $n$ times differentiable but not $n+1$ times.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing the point but surely this does not answer the question.  It seems to me that this gives a function $f$ for which $f'$ is not differentiable - but the question asked about a function $f$ for which $f'$ is not continuous.

Comment: @David: reading again, you are correct.  I should have suggested integrating a step function.  The first function that came to mind for my example was $f(x)=|x|$, but when integrated the derivative is continuous.

Comment: Sorry but I don't think a step function works either: if $f$ is the integral of a step function then $f'$ does not exist at the "step".  I **think** my example works, would you care to check it out and let me know what you think?