# Left Hand Derivative Definition

Tags: derivatives, definition

What is the actual definition of Left Hand Derivative?

I bumped into this [site](http://archives.math.utk.edu/visual.calculus/2/definition.12/) and the second white box on their site gives the definition. Is that wrong?
What is the correct one then?

Comment: Left hand Derivative is just left derivative. Instead like taking derivative from both sides of the def of derivative, left derivative only take the limit from left side.

Comment: @BrianDing Can you please check that link ? It says something else though I totally agree with you.

Comment: I check the link actually and said the above. A second look shows that the def using $\lim_{h\rightarrow a-} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$ is problematic and it should be $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0-} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The **left-hand** and **right-hand derivatives** of $f$ at $a$ are defined by
$$
f'_{-}(a)=\lim_{h\to 0^-}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}
$$
and
$$
f'_{+}(a)=\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}
$$
if these limits exist. Then $f'(a)$ exists if and only if these one-sided derivatives exist and are equal.

Comment: Finally right...

Comment: Is it correct to write the right-hand derivative as $$
f'_{-}(a)=\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(a-h)-f(a)}{-h}
$$                                                                                                              
                                                                                                             

(basically replacing $ lim_{h\to 0^-}$ by $lim_{-h\to 0^+}$)?

Comment: @InternetGuy yes. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/232681/587094

Comment: @DanielWFarlow don't f'_ (a) and $f'(a^+)$ mean the same thing?