# Does a function being not differentiable imply it's continuous?

Tags: continuity

My textbook defines $p = f'(a^{+})$ and $q= f'({a^-})$, and says;

(I) p=q =>f is differentiable at x = a => f is continuous at x = a

(II)p$\ne$q  => f is not differentiable at x = a, but f is continuous at x=a.

How does the second one work out? It needn't be continuous, right?

Comment: One thing to take note of is $p$ and $q$ are differentials. So at $a$, $f$ have to be continuous to allow $p$ and $q$ to be defined.

Comment: Aren't p and q differentials of f(x) at a+h and a-h, and not at a? Like, for f(x)={|x|, when x$\ne$0, 1, when x=0} f'(a+h) and f'(a-h) are defined, but the function isn't continuous at x=0.

Comment: Not exactly. A differential of $f$ at point $a$ ($f'(a)$) is defined as the gradient between $f(a)$ and $f(a+h)$ where $\lim_{h\rightarrow a}$. So $p$ and $q$ are both differentials at point $a$, but from different directions. Another thing is that for $f(x)=|x|$, x is continuous at x=0! (Continuous does not imply smooth! Continuity is defined by the limit from both left and right direction to be equal). It is however not differentiable (aka not smooth).

Comment: Oh, so $p = \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$ and $q = \frac{f(a)-f(a-h)}{h}$, when h is a miniscule positive value, right? But why exactly does f have to be continuous for either of these to exist? And also, I didn't say |x|, i said f(x)=0 at x=0, and f(x)=|x| everywhere else.

Comment: $p$ and $q$ can exist without continuity of $f$ at $a$. Keep in mind $p$ and $q$ are both either from left or right limit of $f$. What would not exist if $f$ is discontinuous at $a$ is $f'(a)$, as can be seen from the inequality of $p$ and $q$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)$ is defined in some neighbourhood of $a\in\mathbb R$ and both $\lim_{x\to a^-}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ and $\lim_{x\to a^+}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ exist (as finite numbers), then $f(x)$ will be continuous at $x=a$.

This is because $f(x)=f(a)+(x-a)\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ so, if, say, $\lim_{x\to a^-}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=p$, then $\lim_{x\to a^-}f(x)=f(a)+0\cdot p= f(a)$, and similar for the limit "from above".

Comment: What if there's a jump discontinuity at a? Then your conditions would be satisfied and f would still be discontinuous.

Comment: @HarryHolmes You did not say how you've defined $f'(a^{-})$ or $f'(a^{+})$. If they are defined as I define them above, then on the jump discontinuity at least one of them, or maybe both, won't exist. Note the definitions above explicitly involve $f(a)$.If by $f'(a^{-})$ you mean $\lim_{x\to a^{-}}f'(x)$, then this is a different beast and obeys different laws.

Comment: They're not defined in any particular way; the textbook states it as a general rule. Wouldn't it go wrong if there *was* a jump discontinuity? As in, $f(x)= x+3$ if $x \geq 0$, and $-3-x$ for $x \lt 0$?

Comment: @HarryHolmes If $f(x)=x+3$ for $x\ge 0$, it means $f(0)=3$ and thus $\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}\frac{-6-x}{x}=\infty$ so $f'(0^{-})$ does not exist. Compare that with $\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}f'(x)=\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}-1 = -1$ which does exist. My point is - both $\lim_{x\to a^{-}}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ and $\lim_{x\to a^{-}}f'(x)$ tell you something about the behaviour of the function on the "left" side of $a$ - but they tell you different things. My guess is that your textbook either explicitly or implicitly adopts the first formula as the definition of $f'(a^{-})$.

Comment: [Yes, aren't they the same?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1158524/527653)

Comment: "Aren't they the same" - who are "they"? Anyways, I am glad you have provided this link - they use the same definition of the left and right derivative that I've been using. With this definition, as I said, if any of those one-sided derivatives exists (as a *finite* number), then the function must be at least one-sided continuous in $a$ (on that side). I am struggling to understand if there are any further points that you want to have clarified.

Comment: By "they", I meant $\lim_{x\to a^{-}}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ and $\lim_{x\to a^{-}}f'(x)$, that you said weren't equal yesterday. Just this; aren't $f'_{-}(a)$ and $\lim_{x\to a^{-}}f'(x)$ equal? Because the answer I linked says that $f'_{-}(a)$ is equal to $\lim_{x\to a^{-}}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$. If they are equal, it would imply that your earlier statement was incorrect.

Comment: I maintain that $f'_{-}(a)$ and $\lim_{x\to a^{-}}f'(x)$ are not the same thing - which your sample above demonstrates. ($f'_{-}(0)$ does not exist, while $\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}f'(x)=-1$ exists). I am not saying those two limits are not *related*: in fact, if the function happens to be left-continuous when $x\to a^{-}$ and if $\lim_{x\to a^{-}}f'(x)$ exists, then $f'_{-}(a)$ also exists and is equal to the previous (you can use mean value theorem to prove this!) but you have to *assume* (left-)continuity - cannot *prove* it.

Comment: (Cont'd): The answer you linked does not say anything similar to what you claim it says, so I am not sure I fully understand what you mean. It only says that, if $f'_{-}(a)$ and $f'_{+}(a)$ exist (i.e. the left- and right-side derivative exist) *and are equal*, then the "full" both-sided derivative $f'(a)$ exists and is equal to both.

Comment: (Cont'd): Note $f'_{-}(a)$ may exist without $\lim_{x\to a^{-}}f'(x)$ existing too, in fact the function doesn't need to be differentiable (or even continuous) in *any* left neighbourhood of $a$. Look at the function $f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2&x\in\mathbb Q\\0&x\not\in\mathbb Q\end{cases}$. This function is continuous *and* differentiable at $x=0$ and is not even continuous (let alone differentiable) at any other point.

Comment: (Cont'd): I am *guessing* that you may be confused about the definition of $f'_{-}(a)$. As the other post says, it is *defined* as $\lim_{x\to a^{-}}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$. It is *not* defined as $\lim_{x\to a^{-}}f'(x)$ and nobody claims that *that* limit is equal to $\lim_{x\to a^{-}}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$.

Comment: Yeah, I'm confused about the notation. Since this thread got a bit messy, I [posted a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3911451/basic-notation-in-limits?noredirect=1#comment8067063_3911451), and it looks like all the notations mean the same thing.

Comment: Yep, I've been trying to say that third and fourth are not the same. Cf. the answer (the only one you've got by now): https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3911571/700480