# Basic notation in limits

Tags: notation, graphing-functions

What is the difference between $f'(a^+)$, $f'_+(a)$, $\lim_{x\to a^{+}}f'(x)$, and $\lim_{x\to a^{+}}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$? I assume they're all the same, but I'm not sure; don't they all essentially mean "the slope of the graph of f(x) just after the point x=a"?

Edit: I could used the left-hand limit with the negative sign, I know; I just used this for convenience. Other than that, is there any difference between any of these?

Comment: The $+$ or $-$ refers to the "side" of the limit; the $+$ means that you're approaching the limit point from the right hand side, while $-$ means you're approaching from the left hand side. This might be a useful link if you haven't seen one-sided limits before: https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calci/onesidedlimits.aspx

Comment: I know that! It could be either + or - that I used, I used the first just because.

Comment: Depends on context, I guess. At an elementary level, they can be thought to notate the same thing, which is the right hand derivative of $f$ at $x=a$; however, the second notation in your question can also refer to the [Dini derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini_derivative) which is not the same thing. Also, they are uncommon notations imo, best to go with the fourth one which is explicit.

Comment: I would identify all four as left-hand derivatives, with some hesitation about the second.

Comment: @YvesDaoust [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1158510/left-hand-derivative-definition) is where I found that one. Looks legit.

Comment: @scoopfaze: The third one is different. (See my answer below.)

Comment: @YvesDaoust: You mean right-hand. Anyway, the second one is standard notation (at least it's what I learned in calculus class long time ago, and it's used by author such as Zorich and Stromberg, for example). It's the third one that you should hesitate about...

Comment: @HansLundmark: yes I mean right-hand.

Answer (score 3):

The third one, $\lim_{x \to a^+} f'(x)$, is different! *If* that limit exists and $f$ is continuous at $a$, then it equals the right-hand derivative $f'_+(a)$, as can be [shown using the mean value theorem for derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257907/prove-that-fa-lim-x-rightarrow-afx). But it may happen that it doesn't exist even if $f'_+(a)$ exists, as shown by the [standard examples of differentiable but not continuously differentiable functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/423279/1242). At it may also exist if $f$ is discontinuous at $a$, say $f(x)=0$ for $x \le a$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x>a$, where $\lim_{x \to a^+} f'(x) = \lim_{x \to a^+} 0 = 0$ but $f'_+(a)$ doesn't exist.

The second and the fourth one denote and define, respectively, the right-hand derivate.

Whether the first one, $f'(a^+)$, is supposed to mean the third or the second/fourth alternative is unclear to me. Usually $g(a^+)$ means the right-hand limit of $g$, and with that interpretation, $f'(a^+)$ would mean the right-hand limit of $f'$, i.e., the third alternative. But some people might also use it to denote the right-hand derivative. (And in many cases that's the same thing, so it might not matter much, but as I wrote above, it's not quite equivalent.)

Comment: The second one seems like it could also be used for the positive part of $f'$, evaluated at $a$.

Comment: Okay, so we know the second and the fourth ones are the same. Then, considering the first three alone, if we define f'(x) =g(x) for simplicity, these sources; [1](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-sided_limit) and [2](https://oregonstate.edu/instruct/mth251/cq/Stage3/Lesson/leftRighta.html) and more, all define $\lim_{x \to a^+} g(x) $ to be the right hand limit. Since $f'_+(a)$ is the right hand derivative, as you said, $g_+(a)$ becomes the right hand limit. Doesn't that mean all four are the same?

Comment: @MarkS.: Well, it could, in principle, but it's a standard notation for the right-hand derivative (see for example Zorich, *Mathematical Analysis I*, p. 262).

Comment: @HarryHolmes: No, they need bot be the same, as shown by the **counterexamples** I gave. I don't understand what you are trying to say with your function $g$, but whatever you mean, you should try it out on those counterexamples to see where your argument breaks down.

Comment: I just replaced the function f'(x) with g(x) for simplicity. Considering that, $f'_+(a)=g_+(a)$, and the pages I linked seem to say $\lim_{x \to a^+} g(x)$(what we first defined as
$\lim_{x \to a^+} f'(x)$)
 is the same as the right-hand limit.

Comment: @HarryHolmes: What is $g_+(a)$? I never said anything about that notation. Did you mean $g(a^+)$?

Comment: @MarkS.: Another standard textbook which uses $f'_+$ is Stromberg, *An Introduction to Classical Real Analysis*, p. 171.

Comment: Yes, I meant $g(a^+)$, aren't they the same?

Comment: No, when you define $f'_+(a)$ you consider a difference quotient “based at $a$” and let $h\to 0^+$, there's just one (one-sided) limit involved. When you consider $g(a^+)$ you first define $g(x)$ for $x>a$ by considering a difference quotient “based at $x$” and letting $h \to 0$ (ordinary limit, not one-sided) in that difference quotient, and then you take a *second* (one-sided) limit by letting $x \to a^+$ in the function $g(x)$. The results of these two different procedures are often the same, but *not necessarily*, as the counterexamples show.

Comment: @HarryHolmes: By the way, when you write $g_+$ on its own, it usually means the positive part of $g$, which is the reason for the first comment above (by Mark S.). So when you see the notation $f'_+$, you shouldn't think of it as a subscript ${}_+$ attached to the function $f'$, but rather as the combined symbol ${}'_+$ attached to the function $f$.