# What is the derivative of $f(x) = e^x + x^3 cos(\frac{1}{x})$, where f(0) = 1, at x = 0?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Intuitively, I would think the derivative of the function at x = 0 would be 0, since f(0) = 1, but I am not sure if there is supposed to be a more rigorous way of doing this. Taking the same approach from this post: [Show that the function $g(x) = x^2 \sin(\frac{1}{x}) ,(g(0) = 0)$ is everywhere differentiable and that $g′(0) = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232672/show-that-the-function-gx-x2-sin-frac1x-g0-0-is-everywhere) I find that

$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{e^h + h^3 cos(\frac{1}{h}) - 1}{h}$

This seems to imply that the derivative doesn't exist. Is this the case or am I on the wrong track? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have almost solved the problem. Just have a look at the linked question and you will get your final answer as $f'(0)=1$. Also your first sentence is wrong. The derivative of $f$ at $0$ can not be figured out just by knowing that $f(0)=1$. What made your think that the derivative of $f$ at $0$ should be $0$?

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, except that all your limits should be as $h\to 0$ (**not** $h\to\infty$). This being fixed, rewrite, for $h\neq 0$,
$$
\frac{e^h + h^3 \cos \frac{1}{h} - 1}{h}
= \frac{e^h -1 }{h} + h^2 \cos \frac{1}{h}
$$
Now, 
$$
\lim_{h\to 0} h^2 \cos \frac{1}{h} = 0 
$$
since $\cos$ is bounded (use the Squeeze theorem). And
$$
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{e^h -1 }{h} = \exp'(0) = e^0 = 1
$$
recognizing the definition of the derivative of $\exp$ at $0$.

That leads to 
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^h + h^3 \cos \frac{1}{h} - 1}{h} = \boxed{1}\,.
$$

---

An interesting question is *why did you think that $f(0)=1$ would imply $f'(0)=0$?* There is no reason for that to hold in general...

Comment: My bad, I intended to write h -> 0. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: @MisterMysterious You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It should be $h\rightarrow 0$, so

\begin{align*}
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}&=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{e^{h}+h^{3}\cos(1/h)-1}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{1+h+h^{2}/2!+\cdots+h^{3}\cos(1/h)-1}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{h+h^{2}/2+\cdots+h^{3}\cos(1/h)}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\left(1+h/2+\cdots+h^{2}\cos(1/h)\right)\\
&=1.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{e^h + h^3 cos(\frac{1}{h}) - 1}{h}=$$

$$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{e^h - 1}{h} +    \lim_{h\to0} \frac  { h^3 cos(\frac{1}{h})}{h}=1+0=1 $$