# Proving/Disproving the Converse of the First Derivative Test

Tags: proof-writing

The First Derivative Test says that the function f is continuous on [a,b] and differentiable on (a,b), except possibly at c in (a,b).

a) We can prove that if f ' (x) > 0 for x in (a,c), and f ' (x) < 0 for x in (c,b), then f has a relative maximum at x = c.

Can we prove or disprove the converse of statement a?

Formal and informally.

Comment: The converse is false. It's not so easy to find counterexamples, but they exist. See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3620613/is-the-reverse-of-the-first-derivative-test-statement-true

Comment: @Mark is there a formal way to prove that function using f'(a) = lim (x -> a) f(x)-f(a) / x-a

Answer (score 0):

The opposite needn't to be true; the function
$$ f(x) = x^2 (\sin\frac1x - 1),  x \ne 0, f(0)=0 $$
has maximum at $0$, however, there is no intervals $(a,0), (0,b)$ such that $f'$ is negative on $(a,0)$ and positive on $(0,b)$.